# How to get dates that are due for the following month from a column

Tags: t-sql

I want to bring back all the dates in my column (nextEventDate) where the dates are due for the following month.

Can someone please advise how I would do that in T-SQL?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please clarify

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the due dates.

```
DECLARE @Events TABLE (
    EventID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    EventName NVARCHAR(100),
    StartDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO @Events VALUES
    ('name1','11/01/2014','11/02/2014'),
    ('name2','09/13/2014','09/15/2014'),
    ('name3','11/02/2014','11/03/2014'),
    ('name4','09/14/2014','09/17/2014')

SELECT * FROM @Events WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),111) < StartDate
```

This will give you the month from the start date:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,StartDate),6,2) AS StartDateMonth,* FROM @Events
```

This will give you the current motnh:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,GETDATE(),111),6,2)
```